# Why does one of my 'while' statements execute when another one of my 'while' statements is true?

Tags: c++, while-loop

Note: I am using C++

Why does one of my 'while' statements ('while' number 1) execute anyway when another one of my 'while' statements ('while' number 2) placed above it is valid? This bothers me, because though 'while' number 1 is not true, but 'while' number 2 is true, 'while' number 1 executes anyway instead of 'while' number 2. Can anyone help me, or explain this? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void PancakeGlutton()
{
    int answer;
    cout << "Good morning!" << endl;
    cout << "Would you like to enter pancake data? Press 1 to accept, press 2 to decline: ";
    cin >> answer;

    while (answer == 1) {
        int totalPeople = 10;
        int totalPancakes = 0;
        int input;
        int lowest = 100000;
        int highest = 0;

        for (int i = 9; i >= 0; --i) {
            cout << "How many pancakes did you eat this morning? I will be asking this question " << i << " more times." << endl;
            cin >> input;

            totalPancakes += input;

            if (input >= highest) {
                highest = input;
            }

            if (input <= lowest) {
                lowest = input;
            }
        }

        double pancakeAverage = double(totalPancakes) / double(totalPeople);

        cout << "The total number of pancakes eaten was " << totalPancakes << " pancakes " << endl;
        cout << "The average number of pancakes eaten was " << pancakeAverage << " pancakes " << endl;
        cout << "The highest number of pancakes eaten was " << highest << " pancakes" << endl;
        cout << "The lowest number of pancakes eaten was " << lowest << " pancakes" << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        cout << "Do you want to enter more pancake data? Press 1 to accept, press 2 to decline: ";
        cin >> answer;
    }
    // while number 1:
    while (answer == 2) {
        break;
    }

    // while number 2:
    while (answer != 1 || answer != 2) {
        cout << "Error: please enter a valid answer. 1 or 2? ";
    cin >> answer;
    }
}

int main()
{
    PancakeGlutton();
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (answer != 1 || answer != 2) {
        cout << "Error: please enter a valid answer. 1 or 2? ";
    cin >> answer;
}
```

must be

```
while (answer != 1 && answer != 2) {
        cout << "Error: please enter a valid answer. 1 or 2? ";
    cin >> answer;
}
```

Comment: This helps, but another problem arises- when i enter invalid input and the while loop executes saying "Error: please enter a valid answer. 1 or 2? ", and when i put in correct input in this while loop, i exit out of the program. Any ideas as to how this happens and why I can fix it?

Comment: You can use do ... while and check for correct input. 

do {
 while(answer == 1)
//...
while(answer == 2)

} while(answer != 1 && asnwer != 2)